# How to fix Dynatrace "finished with non-zero exit value 5" happening only on debug build variant

Tags: android, dynatrace

Here's the error on my build output:

> Process 'command
>   '/Users/raymond/Workspace/MyApp/build/tmp/prepareApkit/dynatrace-mobile-agent-android-7.2.4.1262/Android/auto-instrumentor/instrument.sh''
>   finished with non-zero exit value 5

And this is what I get in the dynatrace's log file:

> 2019-08-08 09:30:20.538 SEVERE: APKit-AdkInstrumentor(1): Multidex
>   preprocessing failed Throwable occurred: d: missing application class
>   'Lcom/something/MyApp;' in primary dex file   at at.b(SourceFile:78)
>     at at.a(SourceFile:116)     at at.a(SourceFile:94)  at
>   ax.a(SourceFile:343)  at ax.c(SourceFile:222)     at
>   com.dynatrace.android.instrumentation.AdkInstrumentor.main(SourceFile:261)

This does not happens on the release build variant, only on the debug one. Any hints would be appreciated, thanks in advance.